# How to merge 2 List<T> and removing duplicate values from it in C#

Tags: c#, list, merge, duplicates

I have two lists List that I need to combine in third list and remove duplicate values from that lists

A bit hard to explain, so let me show an example of what the code looks like and what I want as a result, in sample I use int type not ResultAnalysisFileSql class.

first_list = [1, 12, 12, 5]

second_list = [12, 5, 7, 9, 1]

The result of combining the two lists should result in this list:
resulting_list = [1, 12, 5, 7, 9]

You'll notice that the result has the first list, including its two "12" values, and in second_list has an additional 12, 1 and 5 value.

ResultAnalysisFileSql class

```
[Serializable]
    public partial class ResultAnalysisFileSql
    {
        public string FileSql { get; set; }

        public string PathFileSql { get; set; }

        public List<ErrorAnalysisSql> Errors { get; set; }

        public List<WarningAnalysisSql> Warnings{ get; set; }

        public ResultAnalysisFileSql()
        {

        }

        public ResultAnalysisFileSql(string fileSql)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileSql)
                || fileSql.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fileSql", "fileSql is null");
            }

            if (!fileSql.EndsWith(Utility.ExtensionFicherosErrorYWarning))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("fileSql", "Ruta de fichero Sql no tiene extensión " + Utility.ExtensionFicherosErrorYWarning);
            }

            PathFileSql = fileSql;
            FileSql = ObtenerNombreFicheroSql(fileSql);
            Errors = new List<ErrorAnalysisSql>();
            Warnings= new List<WarningAnalysisSql>();
        }

        private string ObtenerNombreFicheroSql(string fileSql)
        {
            var f = Path.GetFileName(fileSql);
            return f.Substring(0, f.IndexOf(Utility.ExtensionFicherosErrorYWarning));
        }


        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (!(obj is ResultAnalysisFileSql))
                return false;

            var t = obj as ResultAnalysisFileSql;
            return t.FileSql== this.FileSql
                && t.PathFileSql == this.PathFileSql
                && t.Errors.Count == this.Errors.Count
                && t.Warnings.Count == this.Warnings.Count;
        }


    }
```

Any sample code for combine and removing duplicates ?

Answer (score 406, accepted):

Have you had a look at [Enumerable.Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union)

> **This method excludes duplicates from the return set**. This is different
> behavior to the Concat
> method, which returns all the elements
> in the input sequences including
> duplicates.

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 12, 12, 5};
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 12, 5, 7, 9, 1 };
List<int> ulist = list1.Union(list2).ToList();

// ulist output : 1, 12, 5, 7, 9
```

Comment: @Dr TJ: Do your person Class implements IEqualityComparer<T>? If so, you'll need to check your GetHashCode and Equals methods. See the Remarks section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx.

Comment: Important to note because I ran into issues using this on 2 different collections: "You can't union two different types, unless one inherits from the other" from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6884940/410937 which yielded a `cannot be inferred from the usage` error.

Answer (score 38):

why not simply eg

```
var newList = list1.Union(list2)/*.Distinct()*//*.ToList()*/;
```

oh ... according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union) you can leave out the `.Distinct()`

> This method excludes duplicates from
> the return set

Answer (score 33):

Union has not good performance : this [article](http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2012/10/18/merge-collections-without-duplicates-in-c) describe about compare them with together

```
var dict = list2.ToDictionary(p => p.Number);
foreach (var person in list1)
{
        dict[person.Number] = person;
}
var merged = dict.Values.ToList();
```

Lists and LINQ merge: 4820ms
Dictionary merge: 16ms
HashSet and IEqualityComparer: 20ms
LINQ Union and IEqualityComparer: 24ms

Comment: Also another benefit of using a dictionary merge -> I have two list coming back from DB data.  And my data has a timestamp field, which is different in the two lists of data.  With the union I get duplicates due to the timestamp being different.  But with the merge I can decide which unique field I want consider in the dictionary.  +1

Comment: Can vary by processor speed, depends what kind of CPU you have.

Comment: And at the end of the article it says, "I prefer LINQ Union because it communicates intent very clearly." ;) (also, there was only a 8 ms difference)

Comment: For small lists where the difference is negligible, `Union` results in cleaner and more readable code. Spending time to hyper-optimise code when it's not slow may incur a maintenance penalty down the road.

Answer (score 18):

Use Linq's Union:

```
using System.Linq;
var l1 = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5 };
var l2 = new List<int>() { 3,5,6,7,8 };
var l3 = l1.Union(l2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 13):

```
    List<int> first_list = new List<int>() {
        1,
        12,
        12,
        5
    };

    List<int> second_list = new List<int>() {
        12,
        5,
        7,
        9,
        1
    };

    var result = first_list.Union(second_list);
```

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate on [fateme maddahi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2575459/fateme-maddahi)'s answer.

If `list2` contains two or more items with duplicate `Number` properties you will get an exception with `ToDictionary`:

```
[System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
```

To avoid this, use this instead:

```
var dict = list2
    .GroupBy(p => p.Number, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

foreach (var person in list1)
{
        dict[person.Number] = person;
}
var merged = dict.Values.ToList();
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519846/create-dictionary-with-linq-and-avoid-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-a)