# C# Remove objects in one IEnumerable from another IEnumerable

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable

I've got a main IEnumerable collection
and another smaller collection which contains some duplicates from the larger collection,

```
   IEnumerable<T> all_objects ;
   IEnumerable<T> some_of_the_objects ;
```

I'm looking for a "better looking" way to remove all the objects from some_of_the_objects
from all_objects , without having to loop through the smaller collection.

```
  foreach(T _object in some_of_the_objects)
  {
      all_objects.Remove(_object); 
  }
```

Comment: on a related matter 
here's an answer about joining tow lists with out 
duplicate values
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031262/how-to-merge-2-listt-with-removing-duplicate-values-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
all_objects = all_objects.Except(some_of_the_objects);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ivan's answer is on the right track; first you might need a home grown equality comparer unless a duplicate is literally another reference to the same object. But if you have a unit of uniqueness (ID, name, some combination of properties), you could pass that func as a predicate to .Except and have the list de-duplicated as you wish.

Comment: the records are references to the same objects, so Ivan's answer seems to work. 
thanks for the info though.