# Need to cast explicitly thru anonymous type in Union()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 var/objects, retrieving thru these 2 functions:

```
private IQueryable<Project> SelectAll_1(...)
{
    return query;
}
```

class Project is:

```
private int ID;
private string col1;
private string col2;
private string col3;
```

and another:

```
private IQueryable<Project_test> SelectAll_2(...)
{
    return query;
}
```

where POCO of  is:

```
private string ID_inString;
private string col1;
private string col2;
private string col3;
```

and i need to perform union on both of them,

```
var P2 = SelectAll_2(...);
var P1 = SelectAll_1(...);

var P3 = P2.Union(P1);
```

but i get an error, mentioning:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Union(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

i saw some people solve it thru' anonymous type, but i not sure how it works. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't union two different types, unless one inherits from the other (for example, you *could* potentially find a union of `IEnumerable<object>` and `IEnumerable<string>`, although that would rarely be useful).

Now in your case, it sounds like `Project` and `Project_test` should really be one type, if the various properties have the same meaning. Currently the ID properties have different types - but is that really necessary or desirable? If they're both identifiers with the same scope, it makes sense to store them in the same representation. If the properties *don't* have the same meaning, you shouldn't be forming a union between them at all. If they *do* have the same meaning, you should try to make both sequences use the same type.

You *could* use anonymous types for this, in this way:

```
var projectedP1 = P1.Select(x => new { x.ID, x.col1, x.col2, x.col3 });
var projectedP2 = P2.Select(x => new { ID = int.Parse(x.ID_inString),
                                            x.col1, x.col2, x.col3 });
var union = projectedP1.Union(projectedP2);
```

Or you could just use one of the existing types:

```
var projectedP1 = P1.Select(x => new Project_test { 
                                     ID_inString = x.ID.ToString(), 
                                     col1 = x.col1, 
                                     col2 = x.col2, 
                                     col3 = x.col3 });
var union = projectedP1.Union(P2);
```

It's not really obvious which of these is a better idea - but I'd go back to *trying* to reconcile the two types if possible, at which point you have no problems anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. creating a new var would cause any performance issue, coz the original var is kinda huge??

Comment: @gan: No it's not. It's a reference, that's all. Besides, LINQ evaluates lazily - just calling Select and Where etc doesn't actually execute the query at all.

Comment: Thanks. it seems no compilation error, but run-time error: The query contains references to items defined on a different data context.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `P2` is an `IQueryable<Project>` while `P3` is an `IQueryable<Project_test>` and you can't union them into one sequence, since they are of different type.

What you need to do is to project both of them into *one common type* with a `Select()` call which <strike>as far as I know must be a named type</strike> according to Jon Skeet can be done with an anonymous type. The initialization blocks that define the anonymous types must have the same number of members, with the same name, in the same order, with the same types to be treated as one type. To project the types with `Select()` you also need to make the properties public to be accessible for the linq methods.

Comment: So long as the properties in the anonymous type construction expressions have the same names, types and order, they'll map to the same type.