# Remove duplicate files in different directories

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` to list files in two separate directories. Some of the files exist in both folders. How can I remove any duplicate files from the combined list?

```
try
{
    corporateFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"\\" + corporateServer, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
}
catch
{
    corporateFiles = new List<string>();
}

try {
    functionalFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"\\" + functionalServer, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
}
catch
{
    functionalFiles = new List<String>();
}
var combinedFiles = corporateFiles.Concat(functionalFiles);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to merge 2 List<T> with removing duplicate values in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031262/how-to-merge-2-listt-with-removing-duplicate-values-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Hash every file (SHA1 will do) and store the result in a `HashSet`. When you come across a file with a hash already existing in the set, delete it.

Comment: The trick is that you only want to consider the file name and not the entire path when removing duplicates.  And then you need to decide which path you want to keep.

Comment: Which path do you want to keep if there are duplicate file names?

Comment: @SonnyChilds If there are duplicates removing the one in functionalfiles should be ok.

Comment: Be aware.  Just because they have the same name does not mean they have the same contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Union` instead of `Concat`:

```
var combinedFiles = corporateFiles.Union(functionalFiles);
```

You can use the overload passing an `IEqualityComparer<string>` to compare using only the name part:

```
var combined = corporateFiles.Union(functionalFiles, new FileNameComparer())

class FileNameComparer : EqualityComparer<string>
{
    public override bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        var name1 = Path.GetFileName(x);
        var name2 = Path.GetFileName(y);
        return name1 == name2;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        var name = Path.GetFileName(obj);
        return name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work since the file names will include the entire path including the different directory names.

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem and why it is marked as answer?!?! With `Union` all we have is a list, containing filenames from both directories. It isn't useful since we only the duplicated names in both directories. We need `Intersect` here...

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev: He wants the files from both lists, but files with the same filename should appears only one

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca: Aw... the title made me think that he wants them physically deleted, so I though he just needs the duplicates... Isn't that the case?

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev: In that case then yes, he will need Intersect. But when he says `How can I remove any duplicate files from the combined list?` I believe he means to the duplicates in the list. :)

Comment: @ArturoMenchacaL Yeah... it's confusing. Anyway, hope he'll make he's mind by reading this...

Answer (score 2):

It seems I cannot satisfy my lust for LINQ.

Here's a one-liner:

```
var combinedFiles = corporateFiles.Concat(functionalFiles.Where(x => !(corporateFiles.Select(y => y.Split('\\').Last()).ToList().Intersect(functionalFiles.Select(y => y.Split('\\').Last()))).Contains(x.Split('\\').Last())));
```

This keeps the filepaths from `corporateFiles`. You can swap them if you prefer otherwise.

I'll attempt to format this to be more readable.

EDIT: Here's the code abstracted out a bit, hopefully more readable:

```
// Get common file names:
var duplicateFileNames = corporateFiles.Select(y => y.Split('\\').Last()).ToList().Intersect(functionalFiles.Select(y => y.Split('\\').Last()));

// Remove entries in 'functionalFiles' that are duplicates:
var functionalFilesWithoutDuplicates = functionalFiles.Where(x => !duplicateFileNames.Contains(x.Split('\\').Last()));

// Combine the un-touched 'corporateFiles' with the filtered 'functionalFiles':
var combinedFiles = corporateFiles.Concat(functionalFilesWithoutDuplicates);
```