# Given 2 C# Lists how to merge them and get only the non duplicated elements from both lists

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have 2 lists in C#

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 78, 92, 100, 37, 81 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 3, 92, 1, 37 };
```

The expected result should be

```
{ 3, 78, 100, 1, 81 }
```

Please note! *Duplicates*: `92` and `37` *doesn't appear* anymore in the new list.
The new list should have non duplicated elements from both lists.

Each list *cannot have duplicated values*.
Ideally i would like to extend it to an object.

I can do it iterating manually both lists finding and removing duplicates.

My question is : Is there a more elegant and compact way to do in with .NET C# ?

Comment: You cannot assign list of `int` to List of `string`

Comment: [The opposite of Intersect()](//stackoverflow.com/q/5620266)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to merge 2 List<T> with removing duplicate values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031262/how-to-merge-2-listt-with-removing-duplicate-values-in-c-sharp)

Comment: none of them should be in the list

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [SymmetricExceptWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.symmetricexceptwith?view=netframework-4.8) or its emulation, e.g.

```
  HashSet<int> result = new HashSet<int>(list1);

  result.SymmetricExceptWith(list2);
```

Let's have a look at the items:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Outcome:

```
  78, 100, 81, 3, 1
```

If you want `List<int>` (not `HashSet<int>`) as a result, add `ToList()`:

```
  List<int> final = result.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = list1.Concat(list2).
             GroupBy((g) => g).Where(d => d.Count() == 1).
             Select(d => d.Key).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intersect both lists then subtract it from their union you will get the result:

```
var result = list1
    .Concat(list2)
    .Except(list1.Intersect(list2))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Distinct() method from Linq, which, given a list containing duplicates, returns distinct elements from a sequence of integers. More on Distinct() [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8) .

Answer (score 0):

```cs
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 78, 92, 100, 37, 81 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 3, 92, 1, 37 };

IEnumerable<int> result = list1
    .Concat(list2)              // Concat both lists to one big list. Don't use Union! It drops the duplicated values!
    .GroupBy(g => g)            // group them by values
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1) // only values which have a count of 1
    .Select(s => s.Key);        // select the values

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```