# How to find duplicates fieldsa in 2 lists of different types and remove them from both lists, in C#

Tags: c#

This is not a duplicate of: [Given 2 C# Lists how to merge them and get only the non duplicated elements from both lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57006634/given-2-c-sharp-lists-how-to-merge-them-and-get-only-the-non-duplicated-elements) since he's looking at lists of the same type.

I have this scenario:

```
class A
{
    string id;
    .... some other stuff
}

class B
{
    string id;
    .... some other stuff
}
```

I would like to remove, both from A and B, elements that share an id field between the two lists.

I can do it in 3 steps: find the common ids, and then delete the records from both lists, but I'm wondering if there is something more elegant.

---

Edit: expected output

> var A = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ] 
>   var B = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

output:

> A = [ 7, 9 ]
>   B = [ 2, 4 ]

but this is showing only the id field; as stated above, the lists are of different types, they just share ids.

Comment: Can you provide input and expected output

Comment: Write your own implementation of `IComparer` for one/each of the classes (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c)

Comment: the id is a string, the comparison is not the problem; the question is if there is a way to do this without doing 3 steps

Comment: It's always 3 steps, but there are ways to make the steps more efficient by using `HashSet`s.  Why not show how you're currently doing it.  Note: since you're looking for a "better" way this might be a better question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Computer programming is neither more nor less than breaking problems down into smaller problems, solving those problems, and combining the solutions. You've done that. You're done! If you want your three steps to appear as one step, make a method, put those three steps in the method, and then call the method and it will appear to the caller that it is one step.

Comment: or, there may be methods which are overall more efficient; for example, it may be possible to delete items from the list as they get scanned; these are very large lists, so I'm looking for other ideas but the most basic implementation; it's not about making it appear as one step

Comment: depending on how big the lists are, you might want to extract HasSet<string> from the lists that only hold the ID and select from the original lists if the id is not in hashset. if your lists are big, your hashsets might take some memory to construct but runtime is fast. if memory is a concern but runtime is not, silply search through your lists. If your Ids are orderable your lists might profit from ordering first. etc.

Comment: let me put this on hold to see if if the list are naturally sorted, because they may be and this could change the options quite a lot; both lists are around 500-800k elements depending on the time and they get updated regularly, which is why I'm looking ideas to speed this up.

Comment: btw, the 2 answers are what I already have: make a list of id and clean both lists; I'm more trying to find a single pass solution

Comment: Are lists A and B guaranteed to be sorted by ID?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out; they are right now, but I'm asking if it's guaranteed or not

Answer (score 1):

You will require three steps, but you can use Linq to simplify the code.

Given two classes which have a property of the same (equatable) type, named "ID":

```
class Test1
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

class Test2
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can find the duplicates and remove them from both lists like so:

```
var dups =
    (from item1 in list1
    join item2 in list2 on item1.ID equals item2.ID
    select item1.ID)
   .ToArray();

list1.RemoveAll(item => dups.Contains(item.ID));
list2.RemoveAll(item => dups.Contains(item.ID));
```

But that is still three steps.

See [.Net Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6YwgYx) for a runnable example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ Lambda expression for elegance:

```
var intersectValues = list2.Select(r => r.Id).Intersect(list1.Select(r => r.Id)).ToList();
list1.RemoveAll(r => intersectValues.Contains(r.Id));
list2.RemoveAll(r => intersectValues.Contains(r.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Matthew Watson's answer you can move all of it to a single LINQ expression with

```
(from item1 in list1
 join item2 in list2 on item1.ID equals item2.ID
 select item1.ID)
   .ToList()
     .ForEach(d => 
     {
         list1.RemoveAll(i1 => d == i1.ID);
         list2.RemoveAll(i2 => d == i2.ID);
     }
);
```

I don't know where you land on the performance scale. The compiler might actually split this up into the three steps steps you already mentioned.

You also lose some readability as the `from ... select` result does not have a 'speaking' name like *duplicates*, to directly tell you what you will be working with in the `ForEach`.

Complete code example at https://gist.github.com/msdeibel/d2f8a97b754cca85fe4bcac130851597

Answer (score 0):

O(n)

```
        var aHash = list<A>.ToHashSet(x=>x.ID);
        var bHash = list<B>.ToHashSet(x=>x.ID);
        var result1 = new List<A>(A.Count);
        var result2 = new List<B>(B.Count);
        int value;
        foreach (A item in list<A>)
        {
            if (!bHash.TryGetValue(item.ID, out value))
                result1.Add(A);
        }
        foreach (B item in list<B>)
        {
            if (!aHash.TryGetValue(item.ID, out value))
                result2.Add(B);
        }
```

Comment: this would be slower since it does 2 passes over each list.

Comment: @Thomas when List Size with 100000 this method take 20ms and other method take 3500ms

Comment: Have you excluded the first pass? linq is always much more expensive on the first execution since it has to compile the expression. if so, this would be interesting and I will do some testing

Comment: @Thomas because when RemoveAll comparing, it takes O(n) times,and when HashSet comparing only take O(1), this method will faster at large data